# Segmentation Fault in C++ (Eigen library)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, eigen

I'm trying to use the Eigen Library to determine least squares solution to an overdetermined linear system.

The code is going into segmentation fault when the matrix size is large, like 6000 rows as shown in the program below. The same program is working when rows = 5000. I read a lot of posts about fixing segmentation faults but I couldn't find anything useful.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <complex>
#define cols 45
#define rows 6000

using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    int i,j;
    Matrix<std::complex<double>, rows,cols> zMat;

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++) {
            zMat(i,j)=std::complex<double>(rand(),rand());
        }
    }

    VectorXcd ampIn(rows);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        ampIn(i)=std::complex<double>(rand(),rand());

    //Solving Matrix equation using QR Decomposition
    VectorXcd solution = zMat.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(ampIn);

    std::cout << "The least-squares solution is:\n" << solution << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your computer will have an upper limit on the size of memory it has, and you might be pushing this.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of `Matrix`, all of the data could be stored on the stack together with the object. The stack is where compilers usually put local variables and arguments, and is a very limited resource. On Windows the default stack size is 1MiB, on Linux it's 8MiB. 45*6000*2*8 (2*8 for the complex object) is over 2MiB, well over the limit for Windows.

Comment: If @Someprogrammerdude's supposition is correct, a simple workaround is to use `unique_ptr<Matrix<...>>` and `make_unique`, instead of `Matrix<...>`.   Then the allocation for the Matrix object will come from the heap.

Comment: Use MatrixXcd instead of Matrix for data greater than 1 MB

Comment: @mrNAE Solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eigen Library use `MatrixXcd` instead of `Matrix<std::complex<double>...` for data greater than 1 MB

Comment: Usually, it is not worth to use fixed-sized matrices, even for a few kB -- but that strongly depends on the target architecture and the operations which are done.